# chain.DefaultIfException does not catch Exception and sends "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue "

Tags: c#, botframework

I am working to create a bot with Microsoft bot framework. At this stage I am trying to avoid catching exception and “Sorry, my bot code is having an issue” if for example user clicks the button several times.  I have already looked up and found out that “chain.DefaultIfException” can be used. 
I have implemented it as following:

//await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => dialog);

```
                        var dialog = scope.Resolve<IDialog<object>>(TypedParameter.From(checkOutRouteUri));

                        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => dialog.DefaultIfException());
```

However, it still throws Exception and the error message. Is there anything that I might be missing?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

to swallow the exception replace

> () => dialog.DefaultIfException()

with

> () => Chain.From(() =>  dialog).DefaultIfException()